# Angular 4 warning : Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers

Tags: angular

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/Router/@angular/router.es5.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\angular\test2\node_modules\@angular\Router\@angular\router.es5.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\angular\test2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!D:\angular\test2\src\app\login\login.component.ts
* D:\angular\test2\node_modules\@angular\router\@angular\router.es5.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\angular\test2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!D:\angular\test2\src\app\app.module.ts
```

Comment: You should add some of your code, just with the WARNING is almost impossible to know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that aren't entirely clear to me, you've somehow managed to end up with two copies of `@angular/router` installed - one in `node_modules\@angular\router` and one in `node_modules\@angular\Router`.

This is only possible on certain operating systems, hence the warning - if something like this happened in a part of the code you actually checked in to source control, people on systems with case sensitive paths would run into issues trying to check it out.

To get rid of the warning, delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again. This will re-download your dependencies from scratch.